# Remove the overlapping text in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to make a table with lots of columns. I specify width of each column. However, my text in column is overlapping the neighbouring column instead of going to new row.

How do I solve it?

See attached picture:

[image]

Code is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
  \scriptsize
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{P{0.7 cm} P{0.9cm} P{1cm} P{2 cm} P{0.4cm} P{1.2cm} 
   P{0.4cm} P{0.8cm} P{0.5cm} P{0.9cm} }
  Ref & IL & H$\kappa$ & $D_{it}$ & $C_{ox}(\mu F/cm^2)$ & Technique & 
  $\sigma$ & Sn & Strain & Device \\
  \hline
  \cite{gong2012towards} & $SiO_2/Si$ & 3.6 nm Hf$O_2$ & $1.7 \times 10^{12}$(MG)   & 2.2   & CP & - & 3\% & F.S & p-FET \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{No Caption} \label{table: No label}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment, to ensure that the material will fit inside the text block, with a centered version of the package's `X` column for 5 or the 10 columns, to allow automatic line-wrapping if needed. I would also like to suggest that you use the macros of the `siunitx` package to typeset units and numbers. Finally, do use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package to obtain well-spaced lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{tight-spacing = true, per-mode = symbol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \small  % \scriptsize not needed anymore
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c *{5}{C} *{4}{c} @{}}
  Ref & IL & H$\kappa$ & $D_{it}$ & 
  $C_{ox}$ (\si{\micro\farad\per\centi\meter\squared}) & 
  \hspace{0pt}Technique & $\sigma$ & Sn & Strain & Device \\
  \midrule
  \cite{gong2012towards} & $SiO_2/Si$ & 
  \SI{3.6}{\nano\meter} Hf$O_2$ & \num{1.7e12} (MG)   & 
  2.2   & CP & -- & 3\% & F.S & p-FET \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{No Caption} 
  \label{table:NoLabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP left a comment that line-breaks weren't acceptable. If linebreaks aren't acceptable, and if you're not willing to switch to an extremely small font size (which, in my view, you shouldn't do anyway), the main option that's left is to switch to a landscape-oriented table. The following example employs a `sidewaystable` environment, and it uses a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabularx` environment, as automatic text wrapping isn't supposed to happen.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mhchem,rotating,siunitx}
\sisetup{tight-spacing = true, per-mode = symbol}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{9}{c} }
  Ref & IL & H$\kappa$ & $D_{it}$ & 
  $C_{ox}$ (\si{\micro\farad\per\centi\meter\squared}) & 
  Technique & $\sigma$ & Sn & Strain & Device \\
  \midrule
  \cite{gong2012towards} & \ce{SiO2}/\ce{Si} & 
  \SI{3.6}{\nano\meter} \ce{HfO2} & \num{1.7e12} (MG)   & 
  2.2 & CP & -- & 3\% & F.S & p-FET \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \caption{No Caption} 
  \label{table:NoLabel}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico, in your version, I like that the table fits my text block. However, I see that technique coloum also breaks - which I do not want. is there a way out ?

Comment: @Rouge - You have the choice between two not-so-great options: (a) allow line breaks, and use a font size that's readable, and (b) disallow line breaks, and switch to a tiny font that likely nobody will be able to read. When facing this trade-off, I'd choose the first option... A third option, I suppose, would be to see if you really, truly do need all ten columns. Any chance you could get by with "only" [!] 6 or 7 columns? :-)

Comment: @Rouge - A fourth option, I suppose, would be to switch the table's orientation to landscape mode. Obviously, I'm not in a position to judge this option's overall visbility.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I need all of the coloums and if the coloum breaks, the text inside it looks ugly. The text is readable but ofcourse it would be nice if I can somehow increase the size, but I don't see a possible way out. So my main concern at the moment is to fit the table in text block.

Answer (score 3):

A Solution using your code with minimal changes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[h]
  \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
  \scriptsize
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{P{0.7 cm} P{0.9cm} P{1cm} P{2 cm} P{1.2cm} P{1.2cm} 
   P{0.4cm} P{0.8cm} P{0.5cm} P{0.9cm} }
  Ref & IL & H$\kappa$ & $D_{it}$ & $C_{ox}$ $(\mu F/cm^2)$ & Technique & 
  $\sigma$ & Sn & Strain & Device \\
  \hline
  \cite{gong2012towards} & $SiO_2/Si$ & 3.6 nm Hf$O_2$ & $1.7 \times 10^{12}$(MG)   & 2.2   & CP & - & 3\% & F.S & p-FET \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{No Caption} \label{table: No label}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Is there any guarantee that the resulting table will fit inside the text block?

Comment: I added the solution just to show you your mistakes. the first one is that you was expecting that an inline  math expression could be break automatically and this cant be done (You have to break manually). Also \centering is followed only if the width of the column you are giving in P type is greater or at least equal to the real width of the cell's content. (See H_k column that is close to centered but not exactly and Strain title that is righter than wanted). So you have to be careful and give the appropriate width in P type columns and you have to break math expressions manually.

Comment: @Mico... No it is not... I just trying to show OP's mistakes to understand the problem and suggesting to him to chose your answer. Just thought it could help him understand the problem

Comment: her not him :-)

Comment: @Rouge - Sorry! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Some improvements with `booktabs` (adds vertical padding to horizontal rules); `makecell` (allows line breaks in standard cells), `siunitx` (formatting of numbers/units) and `chemformula` since you seem to have some chemical formulae. The `c` column type is enough, without having to calculate column widths by error and trial, and I can use the `\small` fontsize, not `scriptsize` that no one will want to read:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit \uF { \micro \farad }
\usepackage{chemformula}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
 \small% \footnotesize
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
  Ref & IL & H$\kappa$ & $D_\textrm{it}$ & \makecell{$C_\textrm{ox}$\\(\si{\uF/\cm^2})} & Technique &
  $\sigma$ & Sn & Strain & Device \\
  \midrule
  \cite{gong2012towards} & \ch{SiO2}/Si & \makecell{\SI{3.6}{nm}\\ \ch{HfO2}} & \num{1.7e12} (MG) & 2.2 & CP & --- & 3\,\% & F.S & p-FET \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{No Caption} \label{table: No label1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added:*

Playing with the value of `tabcolsep`, the follwing code fits between the margins in `\small` font size:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}%{P{0.7 cm} P{0.9cm} P{1cm} P{2 cm} P{1.2cm} P{1.2cm}
       % P{0.2cm} P{0.3cm} P{0.8cm} P{0.9cm} }
\toprule
Ref & IL & H$\kappa$ & \makecell[t]{$D_\textrm{it}$\\(\si{\cm^{-2}\eV^{-1}})} &
\makecell[t]{$C_\textrm{ox}$\\(\si{\uF/\cm^2})} & Technique &
    $\sigma$ & Sn & Strain & Device \\
\midrule
{} [Gong12] %\cite{gong2012towards}
     & \ch{SiO2}/Si & \makecell{\SI{3.6}{nm}\\
    \ch{HfO2}} &\num{1.7e12}(MG) & 2.2 & CP & --- & 3\,\% & F.S & p--FET
    \\ %
{} [Lee14] %\cite{lee2014epitaxial}
  & \ch{SiO2} & \ch{Yb2O3} & $\sim{}$\num{4e11}(MG)
 & 5 & $G_p/\omega-\omega$ & --- & 5\,\% & \SI{-0.2}{\percent} & pMOS-CAP \\ %
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{No Caption} \label{table: No label}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bernard, thanks your answer helps me ease out a lot of other things too...However, with your code, the size of the table increases and it's extending into the margins (i.e if I dont specify the coloumn width) . is there a way to avoid it ?

Comment: With this very code? Perhaps you don't  load geometry? The default margins are *very* large, because LaTeX supposes you have marginal notes. If you don't use them, just loading `geometry` makes the margins more sensible.  Other than that, one can change the font size to `\footnotesize` (not less,  or no one will read the table), or play the value of `\tabcolsep` (6pt by default, you can go down to 3pt without any problem) or you can use the `adjustwidth` environment. Could you post a typical example?

Comment: Also I get no error when I use chemformula package. However, I see \ch{} appears as a unrecognized command (it get's highlighted). How do I solve it ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean with ‘\ch {}` gets heighlighted’? Highlighted in the editor, or in the .log file?

Comment: Yes I don't use geomtry. Because when I use it, I get an error: Option clash for package geometry. \usepackage . I am not able to get rid of this error.

Comment: This means some other package or you class file already loads it, and you can't load the same file with different options. The solution is not to load it, and pass the option through the document class options. Anyway, the `showframe` option is not for production, but only to check the margins

Comment: @Rouge: I can fit your last  version within margins in a mall font size just with a smaller value of `\tabcolsep` (4 pt instead of 6). Please see my completed answer.

Comment: !!!!!!!! Thanks so much !!! The \tabcolsep is such a big help .. I'm so glad now I don't have to waste time specifying width of each coloumn !!! Thanks a tonn :) :)

Comment: Is there a way when I use \makecell{}, My rows don't get aligned vertically ? (If all rows are aligned from Top, it would be ideal aesthetically}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64507/discussion-between-rouge-and-bernard).